# Angular directive doesn't fire change event in ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-select2

I created a directive for input elements which creates a custom select2 dropdown.
After selecting an element, the original input field (which is used to filter data via the ngModel) is filled with the selected data from the dropdown, but the change event of the input isn't fired.
If I change the input value by hand, the filter is working.

Here is the code of my directive.

```
.directive('ajaxSelect2', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            switch(element.prop("tagName")) {
                case 'INPUT':
                    $timeout(function() {
                        element.select2({
                            [ ... ] //the select2 part
                        });
                    });
                break;
            }

            /* update the input value */
            element.bind("change", function(e) {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope[attrs.ngModel] = e.val;
                });
            });

            scope.$watch(element, function () {
                console.log('x'); //not called
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

I thought the `element.bind("change")` in the `scope.apply()` would trigger a view update, but it doesn't work.
Does anybody have an idea how to tell the ngModel it has new data?

**EDIT:** I figured out, the problem is the ngModel. Because I have to filter several values, my Model is `filter.foobar`. This is not working. If I change the model to `foobar`, it will work. I created a fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/StinsonMaster/6t3Nt/3/

Comment: can you demonstrate the issue in Plunker/Fiddle?

Comment: You need to use `scope.$watch` in a directive on your ngModel to catch the changes.

Comment: I already tried scope.$watch, but it was not called. See edited post.

Comment: It's not called because what you're `watching` needs to be part of the `scope` I guess. You can use a function instead of the `element` variable in the $watch statement.

Comment: I added a fiddle and figured out the problem is the model. I used `filter.foobar` as ngModel which is not working. If I use `foobar` as model it will work. What's the problem there?

Comment: Answer updated... Maybe you could refer my answer. Hope it could be helpful : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a custom select2 dropdown directive. And register the change event handler to element which directive link to. The change event of the input element will be triggered  when I selected a item from dropdown list.
Everything works as expected. You could try my implementation:

Directive

```
.directive('ajaxSelect2',['$timeout', function($timeout){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.select2({
            width: '200px',
            createSearchChoice:function(term, data) { if ($(data).filter(function() { return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0; }).length===0) {return {id:term, text:term};} },
            multiple: true,
            data: [{id: 0, text: 'story'},{id: 1, text: 'bug'},{id: "ccc", text: 'task'}]
        });         
        element.bind("change",function(e){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                scope[attrs.ngModel] = e.val.toString();
            });
        });
    }
  };
}]);
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="selectApp">
  <div ng-controller="selectCtrl">
    <span>Selcted value: {{input}}</span>
    <div>
      <input id="test2" ng-model="input" ajax-select2/>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is the [JSBin DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eHebOti/1/edit)

**[EDIT] For Property access problem**

The ng-model of custom select2 element is "filter.foo". You want to notify the angular world that the value of ng-model have been updated by select2 dropdown filter. But you can't access the second level property like this:

```
scope[attrs.ngModel] = e.val;  // equal to scope['filter.foo'] which is the first level property 'filter.foo'
```

You should access the property in this way:

```
var props = attrs.ngModel.split(".");
if(props.length>1){
  scope[props[0]][props[1]] = e.val;  //[] equals to dot '.'
}else{
  scope[attrs.ngModel] = e.val;
}
```

**Here is a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h4763/)**

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As `element` is not part of the `scope` try with using a [function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch) returning it instead:

```
scope.$watch(function () {
  return element;
}, function () {
  console.log('x');
});
```